# How to replace whitespace with underscore when copy value from form field to another

Tags: javascript, forms, jquery

Someone should be able to find this example for me or give an example..

After hours of searching I found the answer using some bizare search terms in Google only for my 15 month old to close the browser window for me without book marking it! I had private browsing on so it didn't save my history :-(

I have a web form, I need to pass the value of one form field to another form field at the same time replace the white space with underscore using JQuery.

example of what I'm looking for

```
<input name="PageName" id="PageName" type="text" value="All About Us Page" />
<input name="PageURL" id="PageURL" type="hidden" value="all_about_us_page" />
```

so when the form is submitted it gives nice formatted URLs to the page(s) I don't know much about JavaScript or JQuery and how to write variable to make it work.

Hope someone can give a working example, so at least I can get it working and in turn help someone searching in vien for the same solution the title of this should rank pretty high in Google for others to follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little jQuery plugin to do something like this (this would put the value of the *first* matched element into the set of elements matched by the passed in `selector`):

```
$.fn.copyTo = function(selector) {
    $(selector).val($(this[0]).val().replace(/\s/g, "_"));
};
```

Example usage:

```
$("#source").copyTo("#dest");
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/cUTXs/).

Comment: can this be done without clicking the button IE when I tab from one field to another as the whole form will have, PageName = input PageURL = hidden PageContent = TextArea so when I tab from PageName to Page Content the hidden field gets updated?

Comment: Yep it could, you would just have to bind the function to the correct event. Maybe a [`.focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) or [`.keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/).

Comment: can you put a working example with Jquery? as I can't follow what you mean

Comment: No problem, here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/cUTXs/1/). Whenever focus is lost from an `input` all the inputs' content is copied to their equivalent hidden field.

Comment: Cheers Jake from That example I got it to do what I require thanks for the help and an introduction to Fiddle :-)

Answer (score 2):

To copy the value from source, to dest, while replacing whitespace with an underscore, this should do it.

```
$("#dest").val($("#source").val().replace(' ', '_'));
```

Or to get *any* whitespace

```
$("#dest").val($("#source").val().replace(/\s/g, '_'));
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, I'm use what the above does take it should be       <script src="jquery.js"></script>
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#PageURL").val($("#PageName").val().replace(' ', '_'));
    });
   </script> and nothing on the form?

Comment: It does nothing I type in to the first field "this is a test" then tab and press submit but the second Field is still blank?? I even added a 3rd field to see if it was because there was only 2 fields...

Comment: One of your selectors might be wrong.  Also, are you sure this code is running?  Are you getting any errors?

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#PageURL").val($("#PageName").val().replace(/\s/g, '_')); 
 });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="#" method="get" >
<input name="PageName" id="PageName" type="text" value="" />
<input name="PageURL" id="PageURL" type="text" value="" />
<textarea id="PageContent" id="PageContent"></textarea>
<input name="Submit" type="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>

Comment: @ThickyBlack - please create a fiddle that I can look at

Comment: I have no Idea how to create a Fiddle, first time I used it was 1/2 hour ago by the chap below which has resolve my problem :-) thanks for your help...