# Replace space or use regex only aphabets and numbers on search form

Tags: javascript, php, regex, forms

I have this form

```
<form action="search.php" method="get">
Keyword: <input type="text" name="keyword"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and when searching ex. for "FirstName LastName", url is going to

```
example.com/search.php?keyword=FirstName LastName
```

but i want to have this url

```
example.com/search.php?keyword=firstname-lastname
```

do I need with javascript to replace " "(space) with "-", if yes, how?

thanks.

Comment: Form method is POST. Why you worry about url unless you expect to work with raw headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input id="text1" type="text" />
<input id="text2" type="text" />
<button id="test">Test</button>

<script>
$.fn.copyTo = function(selector) {
    $(selector).val($(this[0]).val().replace(/\s/g, "-"));
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#test").click(function() {
        $("#text1").copyTo("#text2");
    });
});
</script>
```

**Source** : 
[How to replace whitespace with underscore when copy value from form field to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539730/how-to-replace-whitespace-with-underscore-when-copy-value-from-form-field-to-ano)

**Example** : http://jsfiddle.net/cUTXs/

Answer (score 0):

```
str = str.replace(/\x20+/g, "-");
```

Comment: For you particular example use `document.getElementsByName("keyword")[0].value` and execute it in `onsubmit`